# Can't close GUI program

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, exit

In my project, I have a dialog that displays that has two buttons. If someone presses "Yes" then I want the program to close. But I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried all of these.

```
qApp->exit();
qApp->quit();
QApplication::exit();
QApplication::quit();
QCoreApplication::exit();
QCoreApplication::quit();
```

And none of these close the program. I tried moving them into my main.cpp, I tried making a second function just for closing, and nothing works.

Would it have anything to do with my event loop earlier that checks for updates? If so, I will post it.

EDIT:

Here is my main.cpp and the function where I want my program to close:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(icons);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    w.checkVersion();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Function:

```
void MainWindow::checkVersion()
{
    if((version != "1.0.0") && (version != ""))//version is a string that is filled when the mainwindow first opens.
    {
        QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
        reply = QMessageBox::question(this, "Update", "Version " + version + " is now available. Would you like to update now?\n\nOr visit http://www.youtube.com/oPryzeLP to download manually.", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);

        if(reply == QMessageBox::Yes)
        {
        }
        QApplication::exit();//moved out of reply just to test closing
    }
}
```

This is the function that contains the event loop:

```
void MainWindow::downloadFile(const QString &url, const QString &aPathInClient)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager* m_NetworkMngr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkReply *reply = m_NetworkMngr->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
    QUrl aUrl(url);
    QFileInfo fileInfo=aUrl.path();

    QFile file(aPathInClient+"\\"+fileInfo.fileName());
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file.write(reply->readAll());
    delete reply;
    loop.quit();
}
```

This is the function that calls downloadFile():

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    downloadFile("link", "stuff");
    QFile info("stuff\\info.txt");
    if(info.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream in(&info);
        while(!in.atEnd())
        {
            version = in.readLine();
            versionLink = in.readLine();
            vidLink = in.readLine();
        }
    }
    info.close();

    setCentralWidget(ui->tabWidget);
    ui->creativeFlag->setEnabled(false);
    ui->structures->setEnabled(false);
    ui->raining->setEnabled(false);
    ui->thundering->setEnabled(false);
    ui->hardcore->setEnabled(false);
    AddSlotsToGroup();
    AddBlocksToGroup();
    QPalette palette = ui->blockFrame->palette();
    palette.setColor( backgroundRole(), QColor( 139, 139, 139 ) );
    ui->blockFrame->setPalette( palette );
    ui->blockFrame->setAutoFillBackground( true );
    QPixmap map_bg(":/images/mapbg.png");
    ui->mapBgLabel->setPixmap(map_bg.scaled(224, 224, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation));
    QShortcut *returnShortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence("Return"), ui->tab_4);
    QObject::connect(returnShortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), ui->blockFind, SLOT(click()));
}
```

Comment: Post a minimum test case that reproduces the problem. Put all the code into one file (main.cpp, for both class declarations and implementation). You can `#include "main.moc"` at the end if you have any `Q_OBJECT` macros within.

Comment: Do you call app.exec() before dialog.exec(), or is the dialog opened directly in main()?

Comment: I will update the post with my main.cpp and the function where I was it to close.

Answer (score 0):

The exit functions you list exit the Qt event loop. In `MainWindow::checkVersion()` you call the exit before the event loop has been started. Even if you already had the loop running, you could start it again (which your code does).

Solution: make it so that the `MainWindow::checkVersion()` returns result code or just a `bool`, then start Qt event loop only if it is ok.

Code (remember to change the prototypes to match):

```
bool MainWindow::checkVersion()
{
    //version is a string that is filled IN MAINWINDOW CONSTRUCTOR, IT SEEMS
    if((version != "1.0.0") && (version != "")) 
    {
        QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
        reply = QMessageBox::question(this, "Update", "Version " + version + " is now available. Would you like to update now?\n\nOr visit http://www.youtube.com/oPryzeLP to download manually.", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);

        // return true if current version is ok
        return !(reply == QMessageBox::Yes);
    }
    else {
        // version is either 1.0.0 or empty
        return true;
}
```

And then `main()` function to match:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(icons);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    if (w.checkVersion()) {
        // version is ok, start the main event loop
        return a.exec();
    } else {
        // user wants to upgrade, do something, or just exit?
        return 0; // or whatever exit code you want
    }
}
```

---

Note that your question code seems to have 3 event loops (hard to be sure with partial code), run one after the other.

1. The local event loop in `MainWindow` constructor, which runs during `loop.exec()` call, and returns when QNAM sends it the signal to exit.
2. The event loop started by `QMessageBox::question()` method, which shows the dialog and exits and returns with result when dialog is closed (I'm not sure if MainWindow is drawn on screen by this event loop or not, since you `show` it before this).
3. The application main event loop, which you enter with `a.exec()`, and then return it's return value as program exit code when it exits (usually this is automatically triggered by last window being closed).

Note that `w.show()` just basically sets a flag that `w` should be visible and sends some event. It does not draw anything yet, and no Qt events get delivered anywhere, until event loop delivers them (duh). Something happens only, when you start the event loop to deliver events.

Another note: MainWindow consturctor is a totally wrong place to do something like that. Ideally an QWidget constructor should just set up the widget, nothing else (no user interaction, no network access). Typical pattern is to just set up the visible stuff there, then have extra initialization method, which you run once the window is actually visible (for example with a single-shot timer, or from overriden `showEvent()`). I suspect this is what you actually want to use for your code.

Comment: Which function should return a result code? And the Qt event loop runs before the checkVersion fucntion. The event loop is used to download a txt file, which from there checkVersion checks the txt file.

Comment: The event loop starts before the closing function. It has to or else the checkVersion function wouldn't know what to display (it displays the result of the event loop)

Comment: I start the event loop in w.show(); The event loop downloads a file to disk where it reads it into a string. Then checkVersion will display the string. How can it display the string if the event loop happens after the checkVersion?

Comment: Yes. I have even commented out anything to do with download file yet my program will still not close when I call the exit function.

Comment: So I should return a bool that will tell my program to quit later? Makes sense. I'll test it out now.

Comment: My program just closes instantly.

Comment: My program closes if I press no.

Comment: Deleted my comments above (you may want to do that too, now it looks a bit funny), and added the stuff to the question. Maybe that will help you to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to exit QEventLoop while it not started yet.
Use std::exit() to stop your program in this case.